# Can't display photo using imageField in models.py of my Django app?

Tags: python, django

In my models.py of my Django PhotoViewer app, I have an imageField defined for my Photo class to display an image on the site. I have uploaded a few photos through Django admin page, but none of them are displayed. I do see all of these photos uploaded in my /static/images folder locally. But when I go to my photo index (list of photos page): `127.0.0.1:8000:photoViewer/photos`, I see the below page instead:

[image]

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
#photoViewer/: (index) photostream (list all photos) 
class Photo (models.Model):
    photo_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #how to retrieve from metadata of file?
    date_taken = models.DateField('date taken', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    photo_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images/", default= "")
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.photo_title
```

photoViewer/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from photoViewer import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #  "photoViewer/photos" 
    url(r'^photos/$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    #  "photoViewer/photos/5/"
    url(r'^photos/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

    #  "photoViewer/albums/"
    # Display list of albums
    url(r'^albums/$', views.AlbumsIndexView.as_view(), name='albumsIndex'),

    #  "photoViewer/albums/1"
    # Display photos for a given album
    url(r'^albums/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.AlbumDetailView.as_view(), name='albumDetail'),

    url(r'^test/$', views.TemplateTestView.as_view(), name='templateTest'),


)
```

photoViewer/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader 
from photoViewer.models import Photo, Album
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.

class TemplateTestView (generic.ListView):
    model = Photo
    template_name = 'photoViewer/test.html'

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    #By default: Uses <app name>/<model name>_detail.html
    #as template
    template_name = 'photoViewer/photo_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_photo_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Photo.objects.order_by('-date_taken')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Photo
    #By default: Uses <app name>/<model name>_detail.html
    #Unless specified by template_name
    template_name = 'photoViewer/photo_detail.html'
    #context_object_name = <new name> 


class AlbumsIndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'photoViewer/albums_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_albums_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.order_by('-date_created')[:5]


class AlbumDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'photoViewer/albums_detail.html'
```

`photoViewer/templates/photoViewer/photo_detail.html` (Template for Photo Detail page):

```
<h1>Photo Detail</h1>
<li>{{ photo.photo_title }}</li>
<li>{{ photo.date_taken }}</li>
<img src="/static/{{ photo.photo_img }}" alt={{ photo.photo_title }}>

<h2>Albums Association</h2>
{% if photo.album_set.all %}
<ul>
    {% for album in photo.album_set.all %}
        <li>{{ album.album_title }}</li>


        <!-- <li><a href="{% url 'photoViewer:detail' photo.id %}">{{ photo.photo_title }}</a>    {{ photo.date_taken }} </li>
 -->
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>This Photo is Not in Any Album</p>
{% endif %}
```

I have the latest version of `pillow` installed

Comment: What does your view look like? What url is your browser trying to load? Does it return a 404, 401 or something else?

Comment: need to see the template and how you access the image field there.

Comment: Just updated my question to include urls.py, views.py, and template file

Comment: How does 404 console output look like in network tab? What is your MEDIA_URL setting? At admin site, in change form of your model, can you click on link and view image in the browser?

Comment: I had changed the img src from "/static/{{ photo.photo_img }}" to "/media/{{ photo.photo_img }}" and it's now working! I noticed in the admin site, the photo link is directed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/, instead of /static as I had thought. Do all photos you upload thru the admin end up in /media instead of /static? How do you put pictures in /static and access /static media then?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you use the model object to show the image, You need use `object.photo_img.url` to access the image path. But before that make sure that photo_img doesn't contain emptry string.

[EDITED]
Your dev server will not serve images until and unless you add a static url to your urls.py entries as mentioned in Django documentation

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

ref : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've just added more file information to my original question. Where do we put "object.photo_img.url"?  I tried replacing the src tag value in "photo_detail.html" with object.photo_img.url and photo.photo_img.url. But there's still no image displayed

Comment: photo_img contains "images/mountain_wallpapers.jpg" and is the correct path inside my static folder for the image

Comment: Pleas note that a both static files and media files are different and are maintained differently. I think you have not added any URL for your dev server. Please have a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development . You need to add 2 URL's for static root and media root

Comment: Ok, So I've done what you had posted. And when I hardcoded an image url in my "templates/photoViewer/photo_detail.html" page, it correctly displayed the image: <img src="{% static "photoViewer/images/mountain_wallpapers.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>

Comment: But when I referred to the photo.photo_img field, it couldn't properly display the image again. <img src="{% static "photoViewer/{{ photo.photo_img }}" %}" alt="My image"/>. I've also tried, photo.photo_img.url, same thing

Comment: photo.photo_img == "images/mountain_wallpapers.jpg". What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Can you give what the browser outputs in HTML source by selecting inspect element of the image in Mozilla Firefox/chrome?

Comment: <img src="/static/photoViewer/%7B%7B%20photo.photo_img%20%7D%7D" alt="My image">

Comment: I think you need not give {{ }} inside static tags.. :)

Comment: Tried <img src="{% static "photoViewer/photo.photo_img" %}" alt="My image"/> and <img src="{% static "photoViewer/photo.photo_img.url" %}" alt="My image"/>

Comment: try using {{ STATIC_URL }} variable instead of using {% static %} tag

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /photoViewer/photos/2/
Could not parse the remainder: ' "photoViewer/photo.photo_img"' from 'STATIC_URL "photoViewer/photo.photo_img"'

Comment: Parameter cannot be passed into STATIC_URL. If you are using
{% static some_variable/string %} it will change to {{ STATIC_URL }}{{ some_variable/string }} after that look into the generated html and make the appropriate changes if any issue arise

Comment: Also put your {{ variable name }} in template to see what the output string that variable will have and paste it here

Answer (score 2):

I always configure my development environment like this:

Django - for processing requests, nginx - for serving static and media.

Also I recomment you to set domain for you development site.

You need to set STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT like this:

```
# settings.py
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
```

**Attention**: don't put you static files into STATIC_ROOT! Create static folder inside each application and then use [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) command. It will go through all installed applications and copy all static from it to STATIC_ROOT. But you need to run this command after you added or edited some files. If you want to edit them often(for js and css files) just use "-l" option for collectstatic command - it'll create links instead of copies.

You should you do this? - Default django development server can process only one request at a time. For example: if you have 10 files on the page, and one file request time is 200ms than it'll take about 2000ms to load a page.
Nginx can process as many requests at a time as you want - total page load time will be about 200ms. It's really nice when you can't even blink in page reload time. Another bonus - you will not see any useless requests in django request log.

With settings shown above django will automatically upload files to MEDIA_ROOT.

Nginx installation is simple: sudo apt-get install nginx

Example nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name myserver.com; #you can set any domain name you like in /etc/hosts
    #just add line 127.0.0.1    myserver.com into it

    access_log  /var/logs/nginx/myserver.log;
    error_log   /var/logs/nginx/myserver.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex off;
        alias /var/www/myserver/static/; # put here path to you static root
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location /media {
        alias /var/www/myserver/media/; # put here path to you media root
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

   if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
      set $host_without_www $1;
       rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
    }

}
```

Put nginx configuration to: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/you_file_name
after it don't forget to reload nginx configuration
    sudo nginx -t  #check configuration
    sudo service nginx reload
    sudo service ngixn restart

If you can't see the picture on the page:

1. Find url in the source code
2. Try to open in directly through browser
3. Check nginx logs

I hope my little advices will help you in hard developer live. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

use {{STATIC_URL}} in template instead of hard coding "/static/".

set STATIC_ROOT to serve your static files properly in your development and server environment.

Comment: DO NOT USE STATIC_URL, but use ``{% load staticfiles %}`` and ``{% static 'myrelative/path/to/file' %}``. Using ``STATIC_URL`` is inflexible, especially about the used protocol and static file mappings not only using a prefix to the filename.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This and make the changes in the SETTINGS.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/subhanshu/mysite/static/'     #put the absolute path 

MEDIA_URL =   '/home/subhanshu/mysite/static/'    #put the absolute path

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

**and make changes to the template like this :**

```
{% for CLASSNAME in Object %}
<img src="/static/{{CLASSNAME.CLASS_OBJECT}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

**If you have some static images that you want to display you can use this:**

```
<img src="{% static 'img/example.jpg' %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should note that static and media files are two different things. Static files are deployed with application, and are for static content (css, js, images for styling-up site). Media files are uploaded an used in models etc.

Next thing: by default django development server is not serving media files. So you should make it to serve them.

And for displaying your image you should use in template code like this:

```
<img src="{{ photo.photo_img.url }}" alt={{ photo.photo_title }}>
```

you don't have to (and shouldn't) add prefix to static or media files by yourself, django will take care of it based on `STATIC_URL` and `MEDIA_URL` from your settings.

Comment: I've uploaded a few .jpeg images using admin, and they've all ended up in my static/ directory. My intention is to create a personal photo portfolio site, where the user uploads photos and let them be displayed on an external site

Comment: If they've ended up in static directory, you configuration is wrong or you're using really outdated django. Show your STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT from your settings.py file.

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static').replace('\\','/')

Comment: My STATIC_ROOT is not set

Comment: So if I'm hosting a personal photo portfolio site, where only the admin (me) can upload photos to the site for others to view, should these pics be static or media content?

Comment: What do you mean by "you should make it (django development server) to serve them (media files)"? How do you do this?

Comment: I tried your given template code, still can't display the image